# Ruby (not rails) CGI script output file for download

Tags: ruby, cgi, attachment

I'm trying to get a script to output a zip file for download.

The script is basically:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'
require 'zip/zip'
require 'cgi'

temp_zip_filename = '/some/path/tmp/' + Time.new.usec.to_s
new_zip = File.open(temp_zip_filename, 'rb'){|f| f.read}

#header = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
#header << ' Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="AZipFile.zip"'

CGI.new.out 'application/zip' do
  new_zip
end
```

I can't see anywhere I can set the downloaded file's name on the requesting computer.  It always seems to get saved as "scriptname.cgi".  Where can I set the content disposition with CGI?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the [`header`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000105) method on CGI:

```
cgi = CGI.new
cgi.header('Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename=AZipFile.zip')
cgi.out 'application/zip' do
    new_zip
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
CGI.new.out(
  "Content-Type" => 'application/zip',
  "content-disposition" => "attachment; filename=#{myfilename}"
){ new_zip }
```

See the documentation for [`CGI#out`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000106).